# Scipy.optimize.minimize for each data

Tags: iteration, scipy-optimize

I have 1000 prediction result of 2 models and true value of them. For each data, I must find b0 and b1 in this equation:  `sqrt((w[i]**(b0+b1*MODEL1[i])*MODEL1[i]+(1-w[i])**(b0+b1*MODEL1[i])*MODEL2[i]-TRUE[i])**2)`

In my model, I bring w[i] value from outside. I have also all ADB[i] (MODEL1), RF[i] (MODEL2) and test_y[i] (TRUE) for each data. The code below could solve only one data in the dataset. However, I must find it for 1000 data, so have 1000 b0 and 1000 b1 at the end of the optimization.

```
def objective(b):
    b0 = b[0]
    b1 = b[1]
    return sqrt((w1[0]**(b0+b1*ADB[0])*ADB[0]+(1-w1[0])**(b0+b1*ADB[0])*RF[0]-test_y[0])**2)

bi = [1,1]
sol= minimize(objective, bi, method='SLSQP')
sol
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two short answers: 1) use numpy arrays. 2) provide a complete example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have provided a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

my complete example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt

# generate 2d regression dataset
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=1100,n_features=2, noise=0.7)
# split into train and test
n_train = 100
train_x, test_x = X[:n_train, :], X[n_train:, :]
train_y, test_y = y[:n_train], y[n_train:]
print(train_x.shape, test_x.shape)


### building the regressors
rgs = []
rfr = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10, random_state=4141, n_jobs=-1)
rfr.fit(train_x, train_y)
print('RF RMSE {score}'.format(score= sqrt(mean_squared_error(test_y, 
rfr.predict(test_x)))))
rgs.append(rfr)

RF = rfr.predict(test_x)

### AdaBoost

ADA = AdaBoostRegressor()
ADA.fit(train_x, train_y)
print('ADA RMSE {score}'.format(score= sqrt(mean_squared_error(test_y, ADA.predict(test_x)))))
rgs.append(ADA)

ADB= ADA.predict(test_x)

# generate random floating point values for w[i]
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import rand
# seed random number generator
seed(511)
# generate random numbers between 0-1
w1 = rand(1000)
```

optimisation for only one data:

```
def objective(b):
    b0 = b[0]
    b1 = b[1]
    return sqrt((w1[0]**(b0+b1*ADB[0])*ADB[0]+(1-w1[0])**(b0+b1*ADB[0])*RF[0]-test_y[0])**2)

bi = [1,0]
sol= minimize(objective, bi, method='SLSQP')
sol
```

I have tried to make  loop but it gives **ValueError: Objective function must return a scalar**

```
loss_es = list()
def objective(b):
    b0 = b[0]
    b1 = b[1]
    for i in range(1000):
        loss = sqrt(((w1[i]**(b0+b1*ADB[i]))*ADB[i]+((1-w1[i])**(b0+b1*ADB[i]))*RF[i]-test_y[i])**2)
        loss_es.append(loss)
    return loss_es

bi = [1,0]

for loss in range(1000):
    sol = minimize(objective, bi, method='SLSQP' )
```

Comment: "ValueError: Objective function must return a scalar" means "Change you objective function to return a scalar value".   You have to *try* to figure it out yourself.

Comment: thank you for your kind response. I have tried to change objective function many times but the result has not changed.

Comment: um your `objective` function returns a list.  In no uncertain terms,  you EXPLICITLY MAKE IT DO EXACTLY THAT.    Your problem is basic python and has nothing to do with minimization.